# In Laravel I'm attempting to get the info from a table with a pivot

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I currently have 3 tables:
medias, colors, media_colors

media_colors is the pivot table I'm trying to use it contains

```
media_id | color_id
------------------
  1      |     1
```

in colors table I have

```
id | front
----------
 1 | color
```

My model for medias contains:

```
public function mediaColors()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany(Color::class, 'media_colors');
}
```

In a controller I attempt to query front like so:

```
$m = Media::find($estimate->media_id);

dd($m->mediaColors[0]->pivot->front);
```

This returns null.  How would I be able to access this?

Comment: how did you get `$m` ? your pivot table has only the keys, so your pivot will be empty. what you're trying to get is the relation not the pivot. `$m->mediaColors[0]->front` directly

Comment: Like this: $m = Media::find($estimate->media_id); @N69S

Comment: It worked as you said! @N69S

Comment: nice, accept the answer (added more details) to close your question.

Comment: Added another easier solution if you only need the first value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the colors directly from the relation collection as marked in the comment.

```
$m = Media::find($estimate->media_id);
foreach($m->mediaColors as $color) {
    //you can access all the colors here
    $fronts[] = $color->front;
}
//or if you only want the first one (if it exists)
$m->mediaColors[0]->front
```

one easier way to get just the first value if you only need that

```
$m = Media::find($estimate->media_id);
$front = $m->mediaColors()->value('front');
// this will return null if no relation found without triggering an exception
```